# Texture looks off in newer version of Blender

Tags: texturing

Sup yall. I have a texture problem. I'm trying to convert a model from an old version of Blender (2.49b) to the most recent version. However the problem with it is after re-linking the texture, it looks wrong. As you can see, the skirt cuts off into a flat color.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

And here is what it looks like in the new version of Blender:

[image]

I've converted some other models the same way but they didn't have any problems. But this one does. Does anyone know if it's possible to fix that?

Comment: Did you check in the shader "options" of the "Image Texture" Node, "N" panel in the shader view, regarding the blend mode? I would guess that the blend mode was set to a different option in the old version.

Comment: This was the issue. I think the blend mode itself was fine, but there's a checkbox that says "Backface culling" that wasn't checked, and once I checked it, that fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As we can see here:

[image: demo pic]

The texture's color space is set to "Raw".
Since it's a simple color data texture and in png format, it should be "sRGB", which is the default color space when you create an image texture node.

Comment: I fiddled with that already, but unfortunately it didn't fix it. If I change it to sRGB it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/01aw3nb.png

Comment: how is your color management panel in the render settings?

Comment: I think those were okay, but I managed to fix it by checking "Backface Culling" under settings in the material properties. Thanks for your reply.